# Selecting items inside jListbox Java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing

Morning all,

I am currently working on a project that involves selected an item from a list box.

The format I am following for the items in the list box is as follows:
(airline name)#(maximum weight)kgs.

My first issue comes with trying to get the item from the list box. I have tried multiple things such as list.getSelectedIndex(); and using a for loop to run through the indexes to try and compare "i" to one of the Airline names but to no avail.

Secondly, do you guys have any suggestions on how I would extract the maximum weight section from my String(SAA#25kgs). My String Handling/Manipulation isn't that great and I would appreciate any suggestions. My first thought was to use .split(), but then I would get the 25**kgs** as well.

The list box I am using looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/328ddeb9b7888821cfe74fecb551dd08

Kind regards IzzVoid,

Comment: Quit reposting questions. You were given advice in your last question on how to improve the question. You have not added new information here or posted a proper image in the forum as asked. And you still haven't used the problem tags when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value from the JList you would do something like this:

```
String stringItem = jList1.getSelectedValue().trim();
```

To get the weight from the selected list item:

```
// Is something in JList selected.
if (jList1.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
    // Yes...Get the selected item from JList.
    String stringItem = jList1.getSelectedValue().trim();
    System.out.println("Selected List Item: " + stringItem);  //Display it.

    // Split the JList item based on the Hash character into a String Array.
    String[] itemParts = stringItem.split("#");
    // Are there two elements within the Array?
    if (itemParts.length > 1) {
        // Yes...Then the 2nd element must be the weight
        String item = itemParts[0];                     // Get ite related to weight
        System.out.println("Item: " + item);            // Display item 
        
        String stringWeight = itemParts[1];             // get weight related to item
        System.out.println("Weight: " + stringWeight);  // Display weight
            
        // Convert weight String to double data type...
        // Remove everything not a digit and convert to double.
        double weight = Double.valueOf(stringWeight.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")); 
        System.out.println("Weight (as double type): " + weight);  // Display weight
    }
    else {
        // No...there is only a single element - Assume No Weight is available!
        System.out.println("No Weight Available!");
    }
}
// No...Nothing appears to be selected in JList.
else {
    System.out.println("Nothing selected!");
}
```